# How to rank data from multiple rows and columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, rank

Example data:

```
>data.frame("A" = c(20,40,53), "B" = c(40,11,60))
```

What's the easiest way in R to get from this

```
   A   B
1 20  40
2 40  11
3 53  60
```

to this?

```
  A       B
1 2.0   3.5
2 3.5   1.0
3 5.0   6.0
```

I couldn't find a way to make rank() or frank() work on multiple rows/columns and googling things like "r rank dataframe" "r rank multiple rows" yielded only questions on how to rank multiple rows/columns *individually*, which is weird, as I suspect the question must have been answered before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `rank` like below

```
df[] <- rank(df)
```

or

```
df <- list2DF(relist(rank(df),skeleton = unclass(df)))
```

and you will get

```
> df
    A   B
1 2.0 3.5
2 3.5 1.0
3 5.0 6.0
```

Comment: Could you explain why ```df[] <- rank(df)``` works while ```df <- rank(df)``` gives an undesired result?

Comment: @Max `[]` reserves the attributes of `df`